# How to get only duplicate values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array and i want to get only duplicates from my array.
How can i do this please help

**I Have this array:**

```
Array
(
[Yeppoon] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => BARACHIEL
                    )

                [RUSSEL LEONARD] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => BARACHIEL
                    )

                [CHRIS NELSON] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => SERIOUS CAPER
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [3] => AL HAMEES
                    )

                [RUSSEL LEONARD] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => EMPEROR MAXIMILIAN
                    )

                [CHRIS NELSON] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => EMPEROR MAXIMILIAN
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [8] => STYLISH LUCK
                    )

                [RUSSEL LEONARD] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => WALK TO THE BAR
                    )

                [CHRIS NELSON] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => ALL HOST
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => MATAGAMI
                    )

                [ANTHONY COLLINS] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => MATAGAMI
                    )

                [JULIE ROWLAND] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => OUR METEOR
                    )

            )
    )

[Goulburn] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => ALL IN RHYTHM
                    )

                [LUKE MARLOW] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => NACHO LIBRE
                    )

                [IAN HUMPHRIES] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => NACHO LIBRE
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [LATE MAIL] => Array
                    (
                        [9] => KIARRA ROSE
                    )

                [LUKE MARLOW] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => USENA
                    )

                [IAN HUMPHRIES] => Array
                    (
                        [9] => KIARRA ROSE
                    )
            )
    )

[Huntingdon] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [RADIO TAB] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => BURNING HEAT
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [RADIO TAB] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => LA BAGUE AU ROI
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [RADIO TAB] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => TUDORS TREASURE
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [RADIO TAB] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => HAMMERSLY LAKE
                    )

            )
    )

[Benalla] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [RICK MCINTOSH] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => MALMAS
                    )

                [KEVIN CASEY] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => MALMAS
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [RICK MCINTOSH] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => UNDER OATH
                    )

                [KEVIN CASEY] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => UNDER OATH
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [RICK MCINTOSH] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => STAR OF SEVILLE
                    )

                [KEVIN CASEY] => Array
                    (
                        [14] => PRATING
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [RICK MCINTOSH] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => ORANGE RIVER
                    )

                [KEVIN CASEY] => Array
                    (
                        [7] => ORANGE RIVER
                    )

            )
    )
)
```

I need to find only duplicate values in array and create new array with duplicates.

**I want this result:**

```
Array
(
[Yeppoon] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
               [5] => BARACHIEL
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [1] => EMPEROR MAXIMILIAN
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
               [4] => MATAGAMI
            )
    )

[Goulburn] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
               [7] => NACHO LIBRE
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [9] => KIARRA ROSE
            )
    )

[Huntingdon] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
               [5] => BURNING HEAT
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [1] => LA BAGUE AU ROI
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
               [7] => TUDORS TREASURE
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
               [2] => HAMMERSLY LAKE
            )
    )

[Benalla] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
               [1] => MALMAS
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
               [6] => UNDER OATH
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
               [7] => ORANGE RIVER
            )
    )
)
```

Thanx a lot!

**It works with the AlexxxTsyk code with this adaptation.**

```
    foreach ($buffer as $key => $array) {
        foreach ($array as $arrKey => $items) {
            foreach ($items as $itemKey => $itemNames) {
                if ((count($itemNames) > 1) OR  (count($items) == 1)) {
                      $arrayYouNeed[$key][$arrKey] = array($itemKey => $itemNames[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayYouHave = array(...);

    $buffer = [];
    foreach ($arrayYouHave as $key => $array) {
        foreach ($array as $itemKey => $items) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $buffer[$key][$itemKey][reset($item)][] = key($item);
            }
        }
    }

$arrayYouNeed = [];

    foreach ($buffer as $key => $array) {
        foreach ($array as $arrKey => $items) {
            foreach ($items as $itemKey => $itemNames) {
                if (count($itemNames) > 1) {
                    $arrayYouNeed[$key][$arrKey][$itemKey] = $itemNames;
                }
            }
        }
    }

echo "<pre>"; die(print_r($arrayYouNeed));
```